# Step-by-step GramSchmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way where Mathematica gives a step-by-step process for orthonormalization of vectors? I have the final result, but I would like to see the process of GramSchmidt to obtain the normalized basis.

Comment: There are many code posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/what-is-the-correct-way-to-perform-the-gram-schmidt-process). Adding a `Print` statement could show the result of each step. (You don't mention it, but I assume you know of the built-in function `Orthogonalize[]`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. But please can you help me by where to write the "Print"? I tried to use some of the code, and it went well by I want to print all the steps, so how could I do that?

Comment: Here you find an step by step intro to Gram Schmidt: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gram-SchmidtOrthonormalization.html

Comment: I cannot tell from your description exactly what you want printed out. And if you can't figure where to put `Print` to print what you want to see, it makes me wonder, what do you want printed? I don't think I can figure that out either.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want to print every step of the GS process, not just the final answer.

Comment: So every time two numbers are added, the addends and the sum should be printed? The same for multiplications and divisions? I doubt it. I imagine you put in `Print` where I would, and printed out a row after it was changed. When I’m confused, I do something on the level of someone who is confused: I print `Print[1 -> x]` where `x` is the data calculated by the first step of the code; then `Print[2 -> y]` at the second step of the code, and so on.  In this way, when I see what I really wanted to print, I know which `Print` statement gave me the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to perform the Gram-Schmidt process?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101450/what-is-the-correct-way-to-perform-the-gram-schmidt-process)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the method in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22040/gram-schmidt-process-for-polynomials).

```
GramSchmidt[w_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{v = ConstantArray[0, Length[w]]}, 
  Table[v[[n]] = 
    w[[n]] - 
     Sum[(v[[i]] . w[[n]]/v[[i]] . v[[i]])*v[[i]], {i, 1, n - 1}], {n,
     1, Length[w]}];
  v]
tmat = {{1, 0, 1}, {2, 6, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 5}};
GramSchmidt[tmat]
```

**Appendix:**

[image]